# Как научиться грамотно ориентироваться в зоопарке плагинов и модулей в вебе (к jQuery и разным CMS)?

Tags: jquery, cms, веб-программирование

Добрый день)

ИМХО, одна из малоприятных особенностей современного программирования по сравнению с счастливыми 90-ми - это гигантский зоопарк всевозможных плагинов, модулей и расширений ко всему чему только можно. Когда в вебе порой надо не столько код писать, сколько мучаться с выбором плагина. Как научиться грамотно и быстро ориентироваться во всем диком многообразии этого "счастья" к jQuery, Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal? Ясно же что все плагины знать невозможно в отличие от самих языков программирования :)

Как Вы находите выход из данного затруднения?

Comment: Выход простой - не влезать в это гэ. Но если уж влезли, то выбора-то на самом деле не так уж и много. Если в 90-е знали только турбо-паскакаль, вы же не изучали MFC для микрософт-си. Так и тут, связавшись с drupal-ом, Вам никогда не понадобится Wordpress.

Comment: Тогда получается, что надо как-то сам мой подход к фрилансу перестраивать, чтобы не нарываться от всякого задержавшегося у меня более чем на 1 задание клиента на Full Stack с веб-"эникеем" и дикий зоопарк CMS. Но в русском сегменте вообще бывает ли "однородно-тематический" фриланс (чтобы устойчиво сидеть в рамках скажем Wordpress+PHP+JS), или лучше поскорее на западный рынок ориентироваться (чего пока боязно из-за каши в голове от того что занимался веб-эникеем последние 3 года)?

Брал с fl.ru заказчиков обычно, все в итоге хотят эникейщика.

Comment: Кстати, если возможно - не могли бы рассказать как кто справляется с проблемой "распыления на эникей"?

Answer (score 1):

> Как научиться грамотно ориентироваться в зоопарке плагинов и модулей в
>   вебе (к jQuery и разным CMS)?

При помощи гугла.

> Как Вы находите выход из данного затруднения?

Не пользуюсь CMS и фреймворками.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Если есть возможность, лучше обойтись без сторонних библиотек и плагинов. Что касается jquery, на сегодня очень много новичков после его использования даже не могёт простую задачу сделать, выполнимую в пару строк на javascript

Comment: Пару строчек конечно на голом javascript гораздо проще, но если требуется серьёзное интерактивное приложение, то без фреймвёрков нормальный человек не справиться. Пока напишет текст программы, второе пришествие наступит, ошибки исправить уже не успеет.

Comment: @Sergey По-моему всё наоборот. Если нужно что то серьёзное - фреймворки бесполезны. Они хороши для решения типовых задач.

Comment: @Sergey, они помогут **быстрее** развернуть код. Но когда дойдёт до вопроса создать что-то действительно индивидуальное, всегда натыкаешься на то, что разработчик по сути **связан** требованиями и философией фреймворка. И редко можно найти такой продукт, чтобы связывал достаточно легко. Т. е. если хочешь создать шедевр и/или поддерживать без ограничений - следует написать самому всё.

Comment: @Other ну я наверно в другой области работаю. Я не дизайню, не создаю шедевры, а простые программки по заколачиванию данных в компьютерную базу. Поменял раскраску - уже шедевр. А так на каждый день, на каждую форму, надо чтобы были поля ввода разных типов, числа, календари, таблицы и т.д. Чтобы изменения в одном элементе, тут же изменяли другой. Всякие диалоги и пр. всплывало. Даже с фреймвёрками это много сложнее чем в delphi, wpf, и более захудалых "десктопных" фреймёрках. Ну на vanila javascript - это только для маньяков-извращенцев.

Comment: @Sergey, так я и написал что если результат работы не кандидат в шедевры (зачем тогда пытаться о_О? :)), то фреймворки реально помогут, т. к. повторный код содержат они. Но это путь тёмной Силы!

Comment: @Other Попутал CMS с CRM. Так-то конечно можно посмотреть на фреймвёрк только если сам ничего не умеешь.

Comment: @Sergey, [ф] заменяют язык на своё API и разбираться уже нужно не в языке, а в API. Этим всё сказано.

Comment: @Sergey, "Даже с фреймвёрками это много сложнее чем в delphi, wpf, и более захудалых "десктопных" фреймёрках."

В точку. Я в 90-е на Turbo Vision (чем не десктопный фреймворк, пусть и для DOS?) отлично кодил аналогичные штуки с формами и календарями, а потом когда после перерыва решил заняться вебом для фриланса - ощущение, что сел в лужу.